# openfeint or gamecenter?

Tags: game-center, openfeint

which one has more potential customers, easier API, and wider feature list? i'm going to develop implement one of those two for highscore recording in my game which ones gives more advantages?

and by the way I might be going to port my game to android, so if you know any thing that can help me not to rewrite my code (for example a C++ wrapper for both of them) that would mean a greate plus for openfeint in my point of veiw.

Comment: This is two distinct questions ("which is better, OF or GC?" and "Are there C++ wrappers for OF?"). The former is too subjective and too much of a feature-list comparison, I think.

Comment: that's exactly a feature list comparison and I just wanted to express having c++ wrapper is considered as a feature to me!

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is way too subjective. Customers aren't going to really care if you use one or the other. Easier APIs are pretty subjective. Why not test them both? And search for the feature lists.

Comment: -1 or use google, here is no problem to solve, you have to do your research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> more potential customers

GameCenter

> easier API

They're all trivially easy

> wider feature list

OpenFeint

> I'm going to develop implement one of those two for highscore recording in my game which ones gives more advantages?

Use GameCenter unless you need some of the features beyond "high score list" that OpenFeint currently provides.

Comment: This answer is out of date now that OpenFeint is no more.